# How can I make a maven test dependent on a class defined in another project's test?

Tags: maven

I have two projects, A, and B. Project A depends on project B. Project B implements several JUnit tests that run properly with maven test. Project B JUnit tests also define some constants that both project A, and B rely on. When I run maven install on project B none of the test classes (namely the constants) make it into the Project B SNAPSHOT jar, so when project A looks for project B's constants it can't find them in project B's SNAPSHOT jar that is installed in my local repo. Is there any way to tell maven to package/install a test SNAPSHOT jar, or something similar so project A can have access to those constants during the test? These constants are only used in the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Simple solution: put the constants in src/main/java and make clear that they're only to be used in test code. Use a short package name like `testing`.
- Overengineered solution: put the constants in a separate maven project (POM only maybe?), referenced by both A and B with scope `test`.

Comment: Another alternative is to copy the constants up into Project A.

Comment: Both of these answers are simply wrong. You should never put test code in your production code, and maven already has a mechanism to cover this.

Comment: @EngineerDollery I agree about not putting test code in production. For the second answer, the separate maven project can be non-production.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if this works, but in a similar situation, I could include a

```
 <classifier>tests</classifier>
```

into the dependency declaration.

You can then have A depend on both on the "unqualified" B and B-tests.

**Update**: [Apparently](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html), you should not use `classifier:test` anymore, but rather `type:test-jar`.