# Maven tests of project depend on code of another project

Tags: maven

This is similar to [How can I make a maven test dependent on a class defined in another project's test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267635/how-can-i-make-a-maven-test-dependent-on-a-class-defined-in-another-projects-te)

I have project A and tests for it.
project B depends on A, and has tests that depend on A/src/java/test. The testing code is using testNG.

I don't see how to make it work. If I move code from A/test to A/main, it means I need to deliver testNG. If I create a new package C, it must depend on A/main and contain all of A/test, and it has to be in C/main (since I need it for B) and therefore doesn't run with "mvn test".

Comment: First if we are talking about unit tests this does not make sense, cause unit tests are independent. So you never should have dependencies between tests. If we are talking about dependencies in Tests code some kind of convenience methods/classes than you should make a separate module which contains the test-code in `src/test/java` take a look here: https://github.com/khmarbaise/maui/tree/master/src/main/resources/ut-example-multi-module-separate-common

Comment: I don't understand. If the code is in a separate_module/src/test/java, I still can't use it in B.

Comment: I assume these two projects are in a multi module project. If they are you can use the deps in B. If those projects are separately it will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a test-jar using the jar plugin and then add that test-jar as a test scoped dependency to the second module.

This is non-optimal because test scoped dependencies are non-transitive so if module A's tests depend on some class that is only on module A's test classpath you will need to repeat the declaration in module B...

This problem suggests that your tests are not correctly designed and could have the common code extracted into a 3rd module (where they will be in `src/main` which should resolve the problem